# Can I redraw a UISegmentedControl programatically? How?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Say I have a UITextField (default blank), a UISegmentedControl (default 2 segments named "1" & "2"), and a UILabel (default text "None") **in my nib**. I want to be able to do the following:

1. I want to enter a number in the UITextField, say "3"
2. I then want to redraw the UISegmentedControl to have 3 segments named "1",
   "2", and "3."
3. I then want to select the segment in the
   UISegmentedControl, and reflect the selection in the UILabel. So if
   I select "3", UILabel will show "3"

I know how to set an IBAction that will catch the number entered in the UITextField, but how do #2 above, that is how do I "redraw" the UISegmentControl to have 3 segments named "1", "2", and "3?"

I know how to do #3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the [insertSegmentWithTitle:(NSString *) atIndex:(NSUInteger) animated:(BOOL)](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/insertSegmentWithTitle:atIndex:animated:) method.

Like:

```
int indexOfSegment = yourSegmentController.numberOfSegments;
[yourSegmentController insertSegmentWithTitle:yourTextfield.text atIndex:indexOfSegment animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I [yourSegmentController removeAllSegments} first, then re-added all the indices just to make sure.